# IP Address increased controlled way at C#

Tags: c#, ip-address

I just want to automatically increase and get IP address which started from any IP range.

For example,

```
10.1.1.255 (passed value that IP to function)
10.1.2.1 (third octet changed, fourth octet set to '1')
```

or

```
10.1.2.11 (passed value that IP to function)
10.1.2.12 (third octet stable, fourth octet increased)
```

Is is possible to do this like above controlled way?

Comment: Be careful, depending on your netmask `10.1.1.255` can be a broadcast address.

Comment: The duplicates required OP to have the IP address as a byte array, which he doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
string[] i = "10.1.1.255".Split('.');

long n = Convert.ToInt64(i[0]) * (long)Math.Pow(256, 3)
        + Convert.ToInt64(i[1]) * (long)Math.Pow(256, 2)
        + Convert.ToInt64(i[2]) * 256
        + Convert.ToInt64(i[3]);

n++;

n = n % (long)Math.Pow(256, 4);

string next = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", n / (int)Math.Pow(256, 3), (n % (int)Math.Pow(256, 3)) / (int)Math.Pow(256, 2), (n % (int)Math.Pow(256, 2)) / 256, n % 256);
```

It splits the IP address in pieces. Calculates a numeric value of it. Then it adds one to get the next, check for overflow. Then it outputs the next value.

Comment: Lol. Figuring out how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: @Rawling: I think the easy option is to use `long`. Can you agree with that?

Comment: Either `long` and modulo it or `uint` and let it wrap around to `0` by itself. I half expected it would work with `int` but I suppose you end up with some negative "bytes".

Comment: Yes, indeed. It becomes negative. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To offer another possible solution, you could use an Extension method on the System.Net.IPAddress class like so:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static System.Net.IPAddress Increment(this System.Net.IPAddress value)
    {
        var ip = BitConverter.ToInt32(value.GetAddressBytes().Reverse().ToArray(), 0);
        ip++;
        return new System.Net.IPAddress(BitConverter.GetBytes(ip).Reverse().ToArray());
    }
}
```

Then, you would use it like this:

```
var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("10.1.1.255");
var newIpAddress = ipAddress.Increment();
```